# Make a hole and fill it up

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode

This should be an easy one, but my model seems to have holes in it.

I want them gone so I can replace them with slits. What is the fastest way to fill these holes?

[image: Behold the holes of your fore fathers.]

I was going to try and use the fill tool.. but due to dirty edges that gets messy quick and running a single edge around the Perimeter is a time suck and still turns out messy. I thought about patching them with circles.. but they still end looking sloppy as you can see on the left. .
maybe if there was an easy way to clean up the edges?  I have like 12 -15 holes to fill and I'd rather not be at it for more hours than I already have been. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way - In Edit mode place above each hole "some" circle like in your screen ... and use **Remesh modifier** (the closest you match original surface the best result modifier gives you. Some polishing can be dome with **Smooth modifier**.

Or according to your object shape, you can try to sculpt roughly the same lowres object and try **Shrinkwrap modifier** ...

... I don't think you have too many options with such topology.

Comment: thank you.. the topology is gross.